# Access schema rules within Controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, mui-x

I use react-hook-forms with schema validation (Zod) and MUI. Now a try to access the validation rules of the corresponding field within the "" tag, to "forward" them to the MUI-Component. For example: I would like to set required option in the MuiTextField, if the validation-rules for the corresponding field contain the required rule - which was derived from the Zod model. The same I try to achieve for things like max and min and other rules. Background is, that I try to have a single type model, which is used for validation but also for input restrictions. I did not yet figure out, out to do that - but it should be possible, I guess. I am also interessted in your approaches to achieve that goal. Thank you for any hint!

Best regards,
Dominic

```
const testSchema = z.object({
  employer: z.string()
});

// ---

const { handleSubmit, control, reset, watch, setValue } = useForm<AddIncomeDto>({
  resolver: zodResolver(testSchema)
});

// ---

<TextField
  name={'employer'}
  label={t('personaldata.employer')}
  placeholder={t('personaldata.employer')}
  control={control}
/>

// ---

<Controller
  name={name}
  control={control}
  render={({ field, fieldState }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <TextField
          error={!!fieldState.error}
          onChange={field.onChange}
          value={field.value || ''}
          {...(!!VALIDATION RULES FOR THIS FIELD CONTAINS REQUIRED!! ? { required: required } : {})}
        />
      </>
    );
  }}
/>
```

A lot of google reseach!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and for the same reasons - single source of logic.

The answer is in the .shape method on the schema, so you would be importing the schema wherever you need to use its rules,
Then you will need to access the .shape() which exists on z.object().
If you use refine() method on your z.object, then you **won't find** .shape(), it will be nested under **_def and .schema** . If you have multiple refine()s then you will need to go through multiple _def.schema, untill you reach the final one where you find .shape().

Here is my use case in react

```js
const newSchema = z.object({ ... });
const schemaShape = newSchema._def.schema._def.schema._def.schema._def.shape();

const maxFriendsRule = schemaShape.friends._def.schema._def.maxLength?.value || Infinity;

// console.log the schema shape and if you're like me then you have even more // refine() on each field (like friends in this example), but when you log you // will see the rules you have defined like minLength, maxlength, regex, etc..

const isFriendsLimitReached = watch("friends").length === maxFriendsRule;

//watch is a react-hook-form method that subscribes for the most recent value of friends array.
```